# Twilio video room not working in cordova hybrid app

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, twilio, cordova-plugins

**Twilio video room chat not working in cordova** hybrid app.local vido load in mobile but remote video not load in mobile app window . How to fix this error?
code is running without any error in all web browser.
we set all type of whitelist and intent and all
as follow

```
<access origin="*"/>
<allow-intent href="http://*/*"/>
<allow-intent href="https://*/*"/>
<allow-intent href="tel:*"/>
<allow-intent href="sms:*"/>
<allow-intent href="mailto:*"/>
<allow-intent href="geo:*"/>
<allow-intent href="market:*"/>
<allow-intent href="data:*"/>
<allow-intent href="*://*.ezhealthpal.com/*"/>
<allow-intent href="*://*.media.twiliocdn.com/*"/>
<allow-intent href="*://*.apis.google.com/*"/>
<allow-intent href="video:*"/>
<allow-intent href="audio:*"/>
<allow-intent href="blob:*"/>
<allow-intent href="*"/>
<allow-navigation href="*"/>
```

Comment: Are you trying to run this app on iOS or Android?

Comment: android greaterthan 4.4

Comment: I don't see why it wouldn't work. You might want to check the [issues for twilio-video.js](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-video.js/issues) to see if anyone has asked about it there. There has definitely been some work on making it work in Cordova. That would be the best place to get the attention of the Video team too.

Comment: Thank you for your support.

Comment: Did you solve this problem? Same issue here. Works fine in mobile BROWSER window, but when served through ionic hybrid, will not allow video or voice, just text